# Why should I vote and accept answers?

Tags: discussion, voting

As a new user, how should I decide to upvote and downvote questions, answers and comments?

Comment: Welcome to Ethereum Stack Exchange Rob! :)

Comment: BTW, there is special stackexchange community for questions about stackexchange: https://meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: This was flagged by several users as belonging on meta.  (One even asks if your account has been compromised.)

Comment: Knowing Rob as an active user i've checked many times the post's date as i thought it was an old post. then i  realized that rob wants to draw our attention to the importance of voting for our site ;D

Answer (score 11):

It's great to welcome so many new users to this forum.

Many new users don't realize that voting activity is an important metric for this site as a whole and for the experts who volunteer their time and knowledge to answer questions. Don't be shy. [Vote early, vote often!](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/vote-early-vote-often)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for voting!

Comment: Should this not be posted on ethereum meta instead of on main?

Answer (score 3):

Voting can encourage and motivate to many answer writer , they will be happy to see that their answers are helping to the people . So keep voting and support them.

Answer (score 3):

Voting is vital for SE sites.

**Voting incentives users to keep answering as the mined ethers incentives the miners to keep mining**. Besides, it helps newcomers to spot easily the best answers.

I'd love to see someday stackexchange enabling voting even for non-logged in users as the vast majority in my opinion doesn't have an account in SE so they don't vote.

for me :

an upvote = thank you