# Is deleting question with no real added value after the solution accepted a proper, correct or moral SE user duty?

Tags: discussion

I made the following [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78837/why-function-that-does-transfer-without-a-mapping-fails/78839?noredirect=1#comment96651_78839), and after being helped I find my mistake pretty shameful for not having reached the conclusion on my own and therefore had to look for help and some (myself) would consider it basic (dumb).

After doing some self examination, I feel that the question was spinned on the wrong assumption of the "behavior" I was experiencing and how solidity built-in functions works, this caused some cognitive dissonance, crashed and made the question.

Being said this, it won't really matter, the question is the question and the answer is the answer. So although solution responder is owned credit and thanks, I don't feel at this point that the question gives any added value as it was based on an erroneus assumption and data input manipulation, yet the answer does give value.

So summary would be:

- Question with no added value***
- Good quality answer***
- Answer is accepted as solution
- No downvotes
- No many views at this point
- Asshamed of making a question which issue was really a Layer8 problem.

So given the facts below would it be reasonable to delete the question?

***Bullet points have the most weight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no user duty to delete such questions.  If you want to delete your own question or answer for whatever reason, there is also no obligation that you should not delete.

In this case, your question title is something that someone could search for, so if you are OK not deleting it, I think it is probably better to keep it on the site.  Your final comment on the answer could also turn out to be the solution for someone else.

---

Interestingly, neither the question or answer (though accepted) was upvoted, until I upvoted both.  (It is odd to me that some of our frequent answerers do not upvote a sizable number of the questions that they answer, despite [Vote early, vote often!](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/vote-early-vote-often) being featured a couple of times on the site.  Sometimes we have questions that get several answers and the question has 0 votes...)